# What is the action for this post method in an HTML form actually going to do?

Tags: decode, encode

I've got an old HTML file with this in it as the post action for a form. What the heck is it?

```
<form id="Form" method="post" action="/47.5/51.5/50/35/55.5/57/54.5/23.5/59.5/50.5/49/51/55.5/57/54.5/54.5/48.‌​5/52.5/54/50.5/57/23/48.5/57.5/56/">
```

The rest of the page is just standard HTML which is why I didn't post it before — and still won't.

To those of you who just down-voted me for not posting more, I specifically said "the post action for a form". This is all I have to go on. If you don't know, fine…but don't down-vote my question because you don't know the answer.

Comment: please update the subject of your question, so it will be clearer.

Comment: It's an URL, the target of the post action of this form. Everything beyond that is wild guessing without any further information about the context.

Comment: How exactly is that a url?

Comment: @user2620542, it's a URL in _exactly_ the same way `www.microsoft.com/download/illegal/copies/of/windows`) is a URL :-)

Answer (score 1):

The action is nothing more than the handler for the form, a URL to be executed when the form is submitted.

It may usually hold something nice such as `"customer_form_submit.php"` but there's nothing stopping anyone from using arbitrarily complex forms such as what you see.

It just means that, when you submit the form, it will post to:

```
<current-protocol-and-server-port-etc>/47.5/51.5/50/35/55.5/57/54.5/23.5/59.5/50.5/49/51/55.5/57/54.5/54.5/48.‌​5/52.5/54/50.5/57/23/48.5/57.5/56/
```

The *code* that sits behind that URL is most likely what you're specifically asking about but, unfortunately, this is not something we're privy to.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I get the concept of a form post, I'm trying to figure out what this 

"/47.5/51.5/50/35/55.5/57/54.5/23.5/59.5/50.5/49/51/55.5/57/54.5/54.5/48.‌​5/52.5/54/50.5/57/23/48.5/57.5/56/" 

is. I can't seem to figure out if it's encoded (I'm pretty sure it is) and if so, with what?

Comment: @user2620542, in terms of the post itself, no, it's not encoded. It's a perfectly valid URL. What happens at the server when you post to that URL is totally up to the server which is why I said that's not something we have access to. You need to go look at the _server_ to see what it's doing with that request.